# Keras: load and process sequence data without memory issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

i want to train a LSTM with tensorflow & Keras. My data are several csv files, each csv file contains several sensor values, the side (can be 1 or 2) and the target. Each csv file is already ordered by time. From my understanding I need for each csv file and each side a separate sequence.

The sequent looks like this:

features = t_n, ... t_n+10

target = t_n+5 --> target is always in the center

First i store all csv files in one pandas df.

On a subset of my data i trained a first model by creating a sequence, here is the code:

```
n_steps = 10
pred_step = 5

def get_data(df):
    trainX = []
    trainY = []
    n = 60 # remove the first an last n rows
    if pred_step<= n_steps:
        for s in [1, 2]:
            df_ = df[df.SIDE==s]
            if df_.empty:
                continue
            else:
                for id in df.ID.unique():
                    df_tmp = df_[df_.ID==id]
                    df_tmp = df_tmp.iloc[n:-n]
                    for i in range(0, len(df_tmp) - n_steps):
                        trainX.append(df_tmp[i:n_steps + i][feat_cols + feat_bin_cols])
                        #trainY.append(df_tmp[n_steps + i-1:n_steps + i][target])
                        trainY.append(df_tmp[pred_step + i:pred_step + 1 + i][target])

    else:
        print('pred step needs to be smaller than n_steps steps')
    return trainX, trainY

trainX, trainY = get_data(df)

trainX, trainY = np.array(trainX), np.array(trainY)

model.fit(trainX, trainY, ...)
```

The code works on the subset of data (probably also not so performant). But if i want to load the whole data it failed due to memory issue.

I think there is an alternative to load the data directly with Keras. But i don't know exactly how. Can someone explain this to me?

BR and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to train in a batch-like fashion if your problem is the limited gpu ram e.g.

```
for epoch in range(epochs)
    for trainX, trainY in batch: 
    # so that you do not load all the data to the memory of the gpu
        model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1,.....) 
    # only one epoch so as to just see all the data in the batch only once
```

If you have a problem with your pc's ram then you could try to read the csv by chunks instead of whole

```
def train_model(epochs=100, number_of_rows=10000, model=None):

    chunk_size = 100
    n_steps = 10
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        chunk = 0
        while chunk < number_of_rows:
            if chunk == 0:
                df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', rows=chunk_size)
            # read the first chunk_size rows
            else:
                df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', skip=range(1, chunk*chunk_size-n_steps))
            trainX, trainY = get_data(df)
            trainX, trainY = np.array(trainX), np.array(trainY)
            model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1)
            chunk += chunk_size
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, this actually works great. I also added threading before the training to increase the speed. Out of curiosity, how can i do the transform to sequences directly in keras?

Comment: What do you mean by directly in keras?